Showing that the compositions $+_i$ in the fundamental double groupoid are well defined.
I'm trying to understand the fundamental double groupoid of a triple of spaces $ \rho_2(X,A,C)$ in the book Nonabelian Algebraic Topology and I'm having some confusion about the proof showing that the compositions are well defined.
To explain, let me first define thin homotopy:
Let $ A \subseteq X$ be a subspace of a topological space $X$ and $ C $ be a collection of points in $A $.
The elements $ \langle \langle \alpha \rangle \rangle \in \rho_2(X, A, C) $ are thin homotopy classes of squares $ \alpha : ( I^2, \partial I^2, \partial^2 I^2 ) \longrightarrow ( X, A, C) $, where by a thin homotopy $ H_t $ from $ \alpha $ to $\alpha'$, we mean a homotopy such that for all $t\in I$, $H_t(c)=H_0(c)$, if $ c \in \partial^2 I^2$ and $H_t(b) \in A $ if $ b \in \partial I^2$. That is, the vertices of the square remain fixed throughout the homotopy and the edges remain in the subspace $A$.
Now given two elements $ \langle \langle \alpha \rangle \rangle, \langle \langle \beta \rangle \rangle \in \rho_2 (X,A,C)$ such that $ \langle \langle \partial^+_{2} \alpha \rangle \rangle = \langle \langle \partial^-_{2} \beta \rangle \rangle $ (that is, there is a homotopy $h$ from the right edge of the square $\alpha$ to the left edge of the square $\beta$ that takes place in $A$ and is relative to the endpoints $x,y$), we need to show that the horizontal composition
$$ ( \alpha +_2 \beta ) (x,y) =\begin{cases} \alpha (x,2y) & 0 \leq y \leq 1/2,\\ \beta(x,2y-1) & 1/2 \leq y \leq 1 \\ \end{cases} $$
is well defined with respect to thin homotopy classes.
The text gives the following proof :


The problem I'm having is that, like the bottom face of the center cube, the top face is also a constant homotopy, i.e., the top face of the cube is sent to the vertex $x$ and the bottom face of the cube is sent to the vertex $y$ since all homotopies are relative to the vertices. So I don't see how the center cube $I^3$ can be projected onto the five faces from a point above the top face.
Edit: I noticed that it's fine to collapse the top face of the cube to $x$ after projecting $ I^3 \longrightarrow A$ provided that the image in $A$ is contractible, and this will give a homotopy from $h$ to $h'$, but it specifically says that no conditions are imposed on the spaces. So this still doesn't seem to work in general.
These pages also have information:
https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/PEOPLE/BROWN/BrownChicago.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.2627
What am I not understanding about this construction?
